# Can not establish a WebSocket connection from JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, struts2, websocket

The application is supposed to update a table whenever a request is made. I have the following code to receive notifications from server. When I run the application it shows followings in alert boxes, seems it is connected but when I call 'send' method of the notification class it does not change anything.

**Alert 1)**

```
       windowfunction connect() {
            wsocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/Notifications");
            alert("got connected");
            document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "arraypv[0]";
            wsocket.onmessage = onMessage;
        }
```

**Alert 2)**

```
      got connected
```

**JavaScript**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var wsocket;
            function connect() {
                wsocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/Notifications");
                alert("got connected");
                wsocket.onmessage = onMessage;
            }
            function onMessage(evt) {
                alert(evt);
                var arraypv = evt;
                alert("array" + arraypv);
                document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = arraypv[0];
            }
            alert("window" + connect);
            window.addEventListener("load", connect, false);
        </script>
```

**Code**

```
@ServerEndpoint("/Notifications")
public class Notifications {

   /* Queue for all open WebSocket sessions */
   static Queue<Session> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();


   public static void send() {
       System.err.println("send");
       String msg = "Here is the message";
      try {
         /* Send updates to all open WebSocket sessions */
         for (Session session : queue) {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText(msg);
         }
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

   @OnOpen
    public void openConnection(Session session) {
        System.err.println("in open connection");
        queue.add(session);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void closedConnection(Session session) {
        System.err.println("in closed connection");
        queue.remove(session);
    }

    @OnError
    public void error(Session session, Throwable t) {
        System.err.println("in error");
        queue.remove(session);
    }
}
```

**Maven**

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-b08</version>
        </dependency>
```

To send a message I use following code in one of my functions

```
     Notifications.send();
```

Console just shows

SEVERE: send

When I trace the connection using FireBug it shows

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:8080/Notifications.
```

Comment: One thing I can confirm that the issue is with your JS client and not the server. I dont have html 5 here so cannot test your JS, but I used a java based client and the server worked fine.

Comment: How are you opening the HTML file? It should be serviced through a webserver on the same host as you want to connect to from javascript and not just opened as a file from disc, or else you will probably run into the security restrictions of the browser.

Comment: I am running it on my localhost. Then how to test it before moving to server?

Answer (score 3):

### Missing Trailing Slash

You forgot the **trailing slash**:
You should connect to

```
ws://localhost:8080/Notifications/
```

instead of

```
ws://localhost:8080/Notifications
```

(Note the trailing slash which is really important).

Also, there are some more problems with your code.
WebSocket is - like almost everything in javascript asynchroneous.
At the point of time where you do your

```
alert("got connected");
```

the websocket is not actaully connected.
Please attach an eventhandler to it like this

```
wsocket.onopen = function() {
    alert("got connected");
};
```

Comment: I applied all the changes but it can not get connected yet and shows Firefox can't ..... Notifications/.

Comment: It also says wsocket.on('open',function(){ is not a function.

Comment: My mistake - Websocket doesn't seem to use eventhandling. Try wsocket.onopen= function() { ... }; instead.

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you using? Older versions of firefox have websocket disabled.

Comment: I am using 29.0.1 which I suppose is the latest one.

Comment: You could use wscat to test whether the server is responding. To do so you'd install node (Linux: apt-get install node), then install ws (Linux: sudo npm install ws --global) and then run wscat on your server